# Can Sonar qube report code coverage difference to AzureDevOps pull request?

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, code-coverage, pull-request

We setup Sonar qube pull request decoration in AzureDevOps.
It report code issues and analyze status to pull request. Also code coverage gathered and can be viewed on Sonar site. Diff coverage also calculated correctly.

But is it possible report coverage back to pull request, so reviewer can take look on difference not leave pull request page? I see on different screenshots, that for github it is possible. But is it possible for AzureDevOps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot do this now, In the azure DevOps, we could see the Sonar report in the Sonar site.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions. And produce team will check the request. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: The link is dead